# CSS Background Opacity Animation

Tags: php, html, css, animation, webkit

I've found a way to make divs change colors rapidly and move with webkit animations, but how can you rapidly change the background opacity in this way? I'm trying to create a flashing effect for the whole page.

Comment: Is your background an image or a CSS gradient? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: It was an image, I figured out the animation part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `animation` in your body/html tag.

```
body {
    -webkit-animation: myanimation 1s;
    animation: myanimation 1s;
}
```

And then do your keyframe stuff.

Comment: You should always put the unprefixed one last.

Comment: Won't this just cause the entire page's opacity to animate? Since from what I recall, changing the opacity of a parent will also change the opacity of all the children within the parent.